# How to get class labels whith non sequential model?

Tags: python, keras

I trained a 9 class image recognition (with bounding boxes) model with Keras. Which has a validation accuracy of 0.85

I've tried using predict_classes but because the model was not sequential it didn't work. Also, I've tried match prediction array to a list with labels which are sorted alphabetically. But it worked neither.

prediction:

```py
kategoriler = ['category0', 'category1', 'category2', 'category3', 'category4', 'category5', 'category6', 'category7', 'category8']


def load_image(img_path, show=False):
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(200, 200))
    img_tensor = image.img_to_array(img)   
    img_tensor = np.expand_dims(img_tensor, axis=0)    
    img_tensor /= 255.    

    return img_tensor

def predict_labels (event,context):
    img_url = event['imageUrl']
    img_id = event['id']
    human_id = event['humanId']


    img_path = '/tmp/img'
    os.system('curl -o ' + img_path + ' ' + img_url)

    new_image = load_image(img_path)

    # check prediction
    pred = model.predict(new_image)
    sonuc = kategoriler[np.argmax(pred[0])]

    response = {
        'id' : img_id,
        'humanId' : human_id,
        'clothes' : {
            'category' : sonuc,
            'subCategory' : '-'
        },
        'pred': str(pred)
    }

    return json.dumps(response)
```

I expect the output of `category6` but the actual output is `0.05920969`

Comment: I removed the unuseful comments from code

Comment: Try `sonuc = categories[np.argmax(pred)]` instead of `sonuc = kategoriler[np.argmax(pred[0])]`

Comment: Sorry for not English and not matching variable names i tried like this but it gives `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'argmax'` error now